# UE4 doesnt work with subfolders

Tags: unreal-4

I am trying to create a file structure for my code in c++classes/Myproject (in UE4 editor). I added a new class and in UE4s "Add C++ Class" dialog box I set the path for the created scripts as MyProject/Source/MyProject/test, test being the subfolder I am trying to create, however when the editor finishes generating the files I get an error saying that it failed to find the files it generated.

> ...\MyProject\test\SysGen.cpp(4): fatal
> error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'test/SysGen.h': No such file
> or directory

In visual studio I can see and open the generated scripts, but it fails to compile. What do I need to do for this to work?

here are the files image taken from visual studio:
[image]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the directory structure in Visual Studio?  This will give us a visual clue as to what the problem is.

Comment: @Stephen ok, I added an image.

Answer (score 1):

From your picture, it seems that the cpp file is trying to look inside a subfolder called test for the header file where there isn't one.

In your #include, remove the test/ and it should clear this up.

Comment: thanks, now it compiles. Only problem is that ue4's UI doesnt show the subfolder

Comment: To get it to show up again, close Visual studio and the editor.  Go into File Explorer and navigate to your game folder.  Delete Binaries, Intermediate and the sln file then right click on your UProject file and choose "Generate Visual Studio Files"